# fix a cell value under one condition, otherwise let the user enter whatever value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question in excel,
say if I have two columns A and B, and I need to set some structure for users to enter value.
If column A = X, then column B must = Y, that is, the value Y must pop up automatically,
Otherwise, column B can be anything user enters.
Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Use data validation on `Column B`

Comment: You're gonna have a hard time trying to mix formula based output and free text in the same range without going through the trouble of using VBA.

Comment: I already used data validation, but Y must pop up automatically and data validation cannot achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if() statement in cell b1:

```
=if(A1=X,Y,C1)
```

Where C1 contains the user input.